# C# - HttpRequest asking for second login credentials

Tags: c#, authentication, ssl, win-universal-app

I am working on a Windows Universal app. In this app I have to show a website in a webview which needs authentication to access. I am accessing it in the following way:

```
    Uri url = new Uri("https://ssl.mywebsite.nl/");
    HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    http.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, userPassword);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await http.GetResponseAsync();
    webView.Source = response.ResponseUri;
```

And this is working perfectly fine on Windows Phone. On windows, however, I get a screen asking me to log in saying:

> "The server ssl.mywebsite.nl is asking for your username and password.
>   The server reports that it is from Please Log In."

Is this a bug in Windows 8.1 or am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: I know this has little to do with the question itself. But thanks to your question I was able to provide the credentials needed for a site. never knew that it had a Credentials property. Now it is working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe the reason this was working on Windows Phone but not on Windows desktop was because it was caching the credentials on Windows Phone but not on Windows. This was leading to succesful future authentication attempts on Windows Phone. And because of the way I was trying to display the retrieved information in the WebView meant it had to re-authenticate itself, leading to a succesful display on Windows Phone but a failed display (or rather a question to authenticate) on Windows.

Solution:

```
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
    .GetBytes(userName + ":" + userPassword));
HttpRequestMessage mess = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, 
    new Uri("https://ssl.mywebsite.nl/"));
mess.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
webView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(mess);
```

This method allows the request to always use the given credentials, therefor not asking the user to provide them.